# Trying to grab certain parts of the NFL stats table using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab each certain stat that is on the table. I have narrowed it down to each column for a team, and just have to grab the actual number! The code I have is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://espn.go.com/nfl/statistics/team/_/stat/defense/position/defense'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
HoustonDefense = soup.find('tr', class_="oddrow team-28-34")
print (HoustonDefense.prettify())
```

This will have the HoustonDefense column printed as this:

```
<tr align="right" class="oddrow team-28-34">
  <td align="left">
    1
  </td>
  <td align="left">
    <a href="http://espn.go.com/nfl/team/_/name/hou/houston-texans">
   Houston
  </a>
  </td>
  <td>
    539
  </td>
  <td>
    272
  </td>
  <td class="sortcell">
    811
  </td>
  <td>
    22.0
  </td>
  <td>
    136
  </td>
  <td>
    65
  </td>
  <td>
    9
  </td>
  <td>
    102
  </td>
  <td>
    38
  </td>
  <td>
    1
  </td>
  <td>
    17
  </td>
  <td>
    5
  </td>
  <td>
    2
  </td>
</tr>
```

I want to grab those numbers between each `<td></td>` and assign them to a variable. Any help would be amazing! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find_all()` to find all `td` elements inside the `tr` and get the text of every `td` found except the first two cells (the ranking and the team name itself):

```
[td.text for td in HoustonDefense.find_all("td")[2:]]
```

Prints:

```
[u'539', u'272', u'811', u'22.0', u'136', u'65', u'9', u'102', u'38', u'1', u'17', u'5', u'2']
```